# working through the Mozilla breakout tutorial in JavaScript but for some reason my paddle isn't being draw why is this?

Tags: javascript

the canvas width being:400px and height being:400px

```
  var paddleHeight = 10;
  var paddleWidth = 75;
  var paddleX = (canvas.width-paddleWidth)/2;
  function drawPaddle(){
  canv.beginPath();
  canv.rect(paddleX,canvas.width-paddleWidth,paddleWidth,paddleHeight);
  canv.fillStyle = "blue";
  canv.fill();
  canv.closePath();
  }drawPaddle();
```

I literally copy pasted Mozilla's code into mine and changed some variable names after a few tries.

Comment: Do you get a JavaScript error on the console?

Comment: Have you instantiated canvas and canv?

Answer (score 0):

With a little editing, I got your code to work. Notably, I got a 2d context from the canvas (which you may have been doing elsewhere), and called it `ctx` instead of `canvas`. I also explicitly set the `height` and `width` of the canvas in the html. If you were previously creating the canvas programatically, `var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')` or something similar, you could specify the size with `canvas.width = '400px'` and `canvas.height = '400px'`. I have included the working code as a snippet below.

```js
  var paddleHeight = 10;
  var paddleWidth = 75;
  var paddleX = (canvas.width - paddleWidth) / 2;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

  function drawPaddle() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.width - paddleWidth, paddleWidth, paddleHeight);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

  drawPaddle();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="400px"/>
```

Comment: oh sorry i failed to mention a setInterval and clearRect call!sorry for wasting your time,thanks!

Comment: Use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) or [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead of setInterval.